# how to make online radio application on android?

Tags: android

I tried to make some test for listening mp3 file which is located in website. It was successfull. But when I tried to listen a link which is online radio, application is doing nothing. No any sounds..

I used :

```
private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource("http://www.buradyo.com/");
        // player.setDataSource("http://cdn.concreteloop.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Jennifer-Lopez-feat.-Pitbull-On-the-Floor.mp3");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}
```

this code is ok for mp3 file but not ok for online radio..

Waiting your help.. Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that `http://www.buradyo.com/` is a valid URL for use with `MediaPlayer`?

Comment: @juniorCoder : how u are saying http://www.buradyo.com/ is an streaming url?

Comment: @juniorCoder No it's not - it's just a webpage with an embedded flashplayer.

Comment: Hmm.. How can I find its stream URL?

Comment: @juniorCoder Always read the HTML source code from where they're streaming.

Answer (score 2):

you are using wrong url for streaming radio from http://www.buradyo.com/ . setDataSource as to stream radio from buradyo.com

```
 String str_stream_url="http://46.137.18.79:8000/;stream.nsv
                                       &type=mp3&volume=75&autostart=true";
 player.setDataSource(str_stream_url);
```

Comment: I tried, but not worked..

Comment: @juniorCoder : this is url for streaming radio from buradyo.com

Comment: @juniorCoder : if u have VLC player installed on system then just paste http://46.137.18.79:8000/;stream.nsv&type=mp3&volume=75&autostart=true url in streaming and check it

Comment: Yes, but when I used this link on browser, no any sound. and also in my app too

Comment: Of course you won't get any sound if you try the link in a browser. You'll just get the raw stream. Probably the `setDataSource` doesn't like the `SHOUTcast` headers in the stream, so try and remove those before sending the stream to the player.

Comment: @juniorCoder : you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) which streaming formats android support

Comment: So I am a JuniorAndroid coder :) I don't understand what I need to do

Comment: @juniorCoder : try http://46.137.18.79:8000/;stream.sdp&type=mp3&volume=75&autostart=true url as setDataSource

Comment: 02-01 22:23:30.400: E/MediaPlayer(13059): start called in state 4
02-01 22:23:30.400: E/MediaPlayer(13059): error (-38, 0)
02-01 22:23:30.430: E/MediaPlayer(13059): Error (-38,0)

Comment: these errors shown in LogCat

Comment: @juniorCoder : this log mean nsv and sdp stream type is not supported by MediaPlayer .

Comment: So what I need to tell BURadyo stuff? Change the stream type?

Comment: @juniorCoder : which version of android u are using in project?

Comment: I tried it on my phone, its 2.3.3

Comment: @juniorCoder : change project android version to 4.0 then try http://46.137.18.79:8000/;stream.sdp&type=mp3&volume=75&autostart=true link as setDataSource to MediaPlayer

Comment: And in project
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Comment: @juniorCoder : u can change android version by right clicking on project then select Properties-> Android and then click on Android 4.o checkbox then on Apply then press OK

Comment: But it means that this app will using only Android version 4.0 and + ??

Comment: @juniorCoder : im just saying try it because RTP or SDP protocols supported by android 3.1 . so if it work then it only work on above from android 3.2

Comment: So, I should try it 4.0 Emulator?

Comment: @juniorCoder: yes try it

Comment: Same :(
02-01 22:47:46.756: E/MediaPlayer(627): start called in state 4
02-01 22:47:46.756: E/MediaPlayer(627): error (-38, 0)
02-01 22:47:46.946: E/MediaPlayer(627): Error (-38,0)

Comment: I did debug and The method setDataSource(String) is undefined for the type for Main

Comment: And it jumps all catch then go to mediaPlayer.start() but The method start() is undefined too..

I didn't understand